# How to send AT commands to the ubox modem on MKR NB 1500

Tags: mkr-gsm-1400

I am trying to send AT commands to the modem to keep the modem always active. I tried the File > Examples > MKRNB > Tools > SerialSarapassThrough example, but that gave me a +CME ERROR: operation not supported. Here is the output for the commands I sent via serial monitor:

```
AT
OK
AT+UPSV=0
+CME ERROR: operation not supported
```

Is there a built in code or any other code which I could use to send that command?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that modem, but if the firmware tells you, that is doesn't support that command, then it doesn't support it. Are you sure, that the modem is capable of what you want?

Comment: yes i am sure, I read the documentation of the modem and it specifies that sending commands will set it up according to my requirement

Comment: Please link to that part of the documentation

Comment: https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/SARA-R4_ATCommands_UBX-17003787.pdf

Comment: The command is : AT+UPSV=0

Answer (score -1):

You have to try SerialSARAPassthrough.ino from examples menu under MKRNB.
If it works properly, you can start writing AT in serial monitor line. You must see answer as OK. Then you can look at the u-blox commands document that is shared above